# Remove strings after match and also exclude null line breaks

Tags: shell, awk, sed

Input:

```
bta01524 Platinum drug resistance - Bos taurus (cow) (1)

  bta:514386 BIRC3

bta01522 Endocrine resistance - Bos taurus (cow) (2)

  bta:280795 FOS
  bta:281848 IGF1R
```

Desired output:

```
bta01524 BIRC3
bta01522 FOS 
bta01522 IGF1R
```

I have been trying the following code, but not able to remove the bta:

```
sed 's%/\bta:/b[^ ]*%%g' output.txt
```

Comment: By `null line breaks` do you mean empty lines or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If row not starts with white space (`/^[^ ]/`) save first column to variable `save`. If row starts with a white space (`/^ /`) and contains columns (`NF!=0`) print variable `save` and content of column 2.

```
awk '/^[^ ]/ {save=$1}; /^ / && NF!=0 {print save,$2}' file
```

Output:

```
bta01524 BIRC3
bta01522 FOS
bta01522 IGF1R
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `sed`, `awk` can provide a nice solution to your problem, e.g.

```
awk '/^\w/{lbl=$1;next} NF>1{print lbl,$NF}' file
```

**Explanation**

- rule 1 - `/^\w{lbl=$1;next}` if the 1st character is a `\w` (word character), set the label (`lbl`) to the first field and get the `next` record;
- rule 2 - `NF>1{print lbl,$NF}` if the number of fields (`NF`) is greater than 1, print the label and the last field.

(**note:** the `'\w'` word-character shorthand requires GNU awk and is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

**Example Use/Output**

Using your input in `file`,

```
$ awk '/^\w/{lbl=$1;next} NF>1{print lbl,$NF}' file
bta01524 BIRC3
bta01522 FOS
bta01522 IGF1R
```

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton. I didn't even think about it until you caught it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/^\S/h;//d;G;s/^.*\s(\S+)\n(\S+).*/\2 \1/p' file
```

If the current line begins with a non-whitespace, make a copy in the hold space and then delete it. Otherwise, append the hold space to the current line and using pattern matching and back references, fashion the desired format. If successful, print the result.

N.B. The option `-n` is set to prevent normal printing and replicate a *grep-like* nature.